# Bookmarket to count IPs in log

Tags: javascript

I have a log file:

```
110.132.134.251 - - [16/Jan/2020:08:57:10 +0000] "HEAD /some_file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172"
110.132.134.251 - - [16/Jan/2020:09:21:25 +0000] "GET /some_file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172"
110.132.134.196 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:29:50 +0000] "HEAD /some_file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172"
110.132.134.196 - - [16/Jan/2020:14:14:12 +0000] "HEAD /some_file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172"
110.132.134.251 - - [16/Jan/2020:15:39:51 +0000] "HEAD /some_file.php HTTP/1.1" 200 296 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172"
```

And need a Bookmarklet that allows me to only count the frequency of IP addresses that appear in that log file.

I have used this [Word Frequency bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/seo.html) which kind of works, but picks up all other text items on the page too, but I just want it to show IP addresses.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20T={},W=[],C=0,s,i;%20function%20F(n){var%20i,x,a,w,t=n.tagName;if(n.nodeType==3){a=n.data.toLowerCase().split(/[\s\(\)\:\,\;\<\>\&\'\"]/);for(i%20in%20a)if(w=a[i]){w="%20"+w;T[w]=T[w]?T[w]+1:1;++C;}}if(t!="SCRIPT"&&t!="STYLE")for(i=0;x=n.childNodes[i];++i)F(x)}F(document);for(i%20in%20T)W.push([T[i],i]);W.sort(function(a,b){var%20x=b[0]-a[0];return%20x?x:((b[1]<a[1])?1:-1)});%20s="<h3>"+C+"%20words</h3>";for(i%20in%20W)s+=W[i][0]+":"+W[i][1]+"<br>";with(open().document){write(s);close()}})()
```

The output could be like this, sorted by the highest frequency:

```
110.132.134.251 = 3
110.132.134.196 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working out the regular expression and tweaking the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20T={},W=[],C=0,s,i;%20function%20F(n){var%20i,x,a,w,t=n.tagName;if(n.nodeType==3){a=n.data.toLowerCase().match(/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/g);for(i%20in%20a)if(w=a[i]){w="%20"+w;T[w]=T[w]?T[w]+1:1;++C;}}if(t!="SCRIPT"&&t!="STYLE")for(i=0;x=n.childNodes[i];++i)F(x)}F(document);for(i%20in%20T)W.push([T[i],i]);W.sort(function(a,b){var%20x=b[0]-a[0];return%20x?x:((b[1]<a[1])?1:-1)});%20s="<h3>IP Address Count</h3>";for(i%20in%20W)s+=W[i][0]+":"+W[i][1]+"<br>";with(open().document){write(s);close()}})()
```